# ¿Como puedo crear una nueva columna con la fecha minima de cada usuario?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente tabla:

| Usuario | Fecha | Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 01/01/2021 | Tipo 1 |
| User1 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 2 |
| User2 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 3 |
| User2 | 01/03/2021 | Tipo 1 |
| User2 | 01/03/2021 | Tipo 1 |
| User2 | 01/04/2021 | Tipo 1 |
| User3 | 01/01/2021 | Tipo 1 |
| User3 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 4 |
| User3 | 01/08/2021 | Tipo 4 |

y quiero que me devuelva

| Usuario | Fecha | Categoria | Fecha_Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 01/01/2021 | Tipo 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| User1 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 2 | 01/01/2021 |
| User2 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 3 | 01/02/2021 |
| User2 | 01/03/2021 | Tipo 1 | 01/02/2021 |
| User2 | 01/03/2021 | Tipo 1 | 01/02/2021 |
| User2 | 01/04/2021 | Tipo 1 | 01/02/2021 |
| User3 | 01/01/2021 | Tipo 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| User3 | 01/02/2021 | Tipo 4 | 01/01/2021 |
| User3 | 01/08/2021 | Tipo 4 | 01/01/2021 |

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Tengo la primera tabla y no se como hacer para crear una columna nueva con la fecha minima de cada usuario.

Comment: Quieres cambiar la estructura de la tabla o simplemente el select?

Comment: Quiero rellenar la nueva columna con la fecha minima de cada usuario

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE (NombreDeTuTabla)
ADD Fecha_Min DATE NULL;

//así crearías el campo que falta en tu tabla...luego tendrías que llenarlo...dependiendo de donde necesites tomar ese dato, si lo quieres llenar a mano puedes usar un INSERT INTO o UPDATE SET.

Comment: Quiero rellenar la nueva columna con la fecha minima de cada usuario.

Comment: La "fecha mínima" que necesitas agregar en la tabla, la Tenes en otra tabla o la queres ingresar vos?
-supongamos que tenes esa fecha en otra tabla y la queres agregar a esta tabla, podrias  joinear las tablas en una consulta y volcar su contenido en una tabla nueva.
-En el caso que tengas que incorporar este dato "fecha minima" como un dato nuevo, tendrias que agregarlos con  INSERT INTO o UPDATE SET.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Si, lo que hice fue crear esa columna y luego un join a la tabla